# Group by count for "True" in collection without key in Query

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework, pymongo

My Data:

```
{"_id": "0x026EFF", "Stations": {"MP": false, "AS": true, "RW": true, "FT": true}},
{"_id": "0x026F00", "Stations": {"MP": null, "AS": true, "RW": true, "FT": false}},
{"_id": "0x026F01", "Stations": {"MP": null, "AS": true, "RW": false, "FT": null}},
{"_id": "0x026F02", "Stations": {"MP": null, "AS": null, "RW": true, "FT": false}},
{"_id": "0x026F03", "Stations": {"MP": null, "AS": true, "RW": null, "FT": false}}
```

Here is my query

```
Collection.aggregate([
    {"$group": {'_id': None,
                'MP': {'$sum': {'$cond': ["$Stations.MP", 1, 0]}},
                'AS': {'$sum': {'$cond': ["$Stations.AS", 1, 0]}},
                'RW': {'$sum': {'$cond': ["$Stations.RW", 1, 0]}},
                'FT': {'$sum': {'$cond': ["$Stations.FT", 1, 0]}}
                }
        },
    {'$project': {'_id': 0}}
])
```

[mongoplayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/Fsuj6CiuxYB)

I got

```
[{"AS":4,"FT":1,"MP":0,"RW":3}]
```

My question is **Can I rewrite my query without "MP", "AS", "RW", "FT"**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. `$set` - Set the `Stations` field with convert `Stations` from key-value pair to an array with the documents of `k` and `v` fields.
2. `$unwind` - Deconstruct `Stations` array to multiple documents.
3. `$group` - Group by `Stations.k` and perform sum by condition.
4. `$group` - Group by `null` to combine all documents into one and push the root document into `data` array.
5. `$replaceWith` - Replace the input document with:

   5.1. `$arrayToObject` - Convert the array from the result *5.1.1* to key-value pair.

   5.1.1. `$map` - Iterate the `data` array and return a new array with the documents containing `k` and `v` fields.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $set: {
      Stations: {
        $objectToArray: "$Stations"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $unwind: "$Stations"
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$Stations.k",
      count: {
        $sum: {
          $cond: {
            if: {
              $eq: [
                "$Stations.v",
                true
              ]
            },
            then: 1,
            else: 0
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: null,
      data: {
        $push: "$$ROOT"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $replaceWith: {
      $arrayToObject: {
        $map: {
          input: "$data",
          in: {
            k: "$$this._id",
            v: "$$this.count"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Demo @ Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/qeFFR6UKT-G)

Comment: More complicated than i thought. My data format is fixed, so I will use the old way, thank you very much!